# To find the number of Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to find the number of Ideals in $\mathbb  { Z}/11\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb { Z}/13\mathbb{Z}$  ?

Comment: Please elaborate more on the question, especially what you have done...

Comment: An ideal of a product of rings is the product of ideals of the rings.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not even sure what you mean by "$\mathbb{Z} / 11 \mathbb{Z}$." Can you explain? And "$\mathbb{Z} / 13 \mathbb{Z}$" is the same thing but with $13$ instead of $11$, right?

Comment: @Bob Happ $\mathbb{Z} / 11 \mathbb{Z}$ is a classical notation for residual classes mod. 11.

Comment: @Jean Marie So that means the ideal $11 \mathbb{Z} = \ldots, -33, -22, -11, 0, 11, 22, 33, \ldots$ and the cosets $11 \mathbb{Z} + 1 = \ldots, -32, -21, -10, 1, 12, 23, 34, \ldots$, $11 \mathbb{Z} + 2 = \ldots, -31, -20, -9, 2, 13, 24, 35, \ldots$ and so on and so forth to $11 \mathbb{Z} + 10$?

Comment: @Bob Happ : that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal of a product of rings is the product of ideals of the rings.

Here $F_{11}=\mathbb{Z} / 11 \mathbb{Z}$ and $F_{13}=\mathbb{Z} / 13 \mathbb{Z}$ are fields (because $11$ and $13$ are prime numbers) therefore have no other ideals than $0$ and themselves.

As a consequence, there are 4 ideals :

$$\{0\} \times \{0\}, \ \ F_{11} \times \{0\}, \ \   \{0\} \times F_{13}, \ \  F_{11} \times F_{13}$$

Comment: Sometimes,  the whole ring, here $F_{11} \times F_{13}$ is excluded when one looks for so-called "proper ideals".

Comment: This question could have been asked under the form : what are the ideals of  $\mathbb{Z} / 143 \mathbb{Z}$ ?...

Answer (score 1):

The $\mathbb Z/11 \mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z $ are fields, so they have two ideals $(0),(1)$. So the ideals of $\mathbb Z/11 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z $ are 
$\{0\}, \{0\}\times \mathbb Z/13 \mathbb Z,\mathbb Z/11 \mathbb Z \times \{0\},\mathbb Z/11 \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/13\mathbb Z  $